# Are there any methods to detect whole multivariate time-series as anomalous from a set of multivariate time-series?

Tags: time-series, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, multivariate-distribution

Consider a scenario with Dataset *D* as {*T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, ..., T<sub>n</sub>*} and *T<sub>i</sub>* is a multivariate time-series of length *m<sub>i</sub>* as {*X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, ..., X<sub>m<sub>i</sub></sub>*}. Here each record of the time-series *X<sub>i</sub>* is a vector of attribute values {*X<sub>i</sub><sup>1</sup>, X<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>, ..., X<sub>i</sub><sup>a</sup>*} where *X<sub>i</sub><sup>j</sup>* is the value of *j<sup>th</sup>* attribute of *i<sup>th</sup>* record of a time series. Given this scenario is there a method to detect the anomalous time-series(or a set of anomalous time series, i.e the *T*'s which are anomalous) from the set *D*?

Comment: Is you problem supervised or unsupervised? Are anomalous observations labeled?

Comment: @Leevo It is unsupervised problem(we will not use labels to train the model), but if you know supervised technique, it would also be helpful.

Comment: It's impossible to go supervised without labeled data, unfortunately

Comment: @Leevo I agree, my problem is unsupervised, but even if you give information about some supervised technique, I will try to study it, follow the references from which it was developed and would try to use it by tweaking it.